# meteor 0.8.3 in a template how to check if a data property is not defined ?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In my attempt to update my app to meteor 0.8.3 i have one problem.
In some templates i want to check if a "price" property exist (or any other property), and i used to do like this:

```
{{#if not price}}
```

it worked in previous version of meteor, but with 0.8.3 i have that error :

```
Exception in queued task: Error: No such function: not
at http : / / myapp.com/packages/blaze.js?309c2a3b573dca998c07c493ba4953d451b2c963:2494:15
....
```

I don't see anything about this in meteor documentation. What am i doign wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `unless`:

```
{{#unless price}}
  ...
{{/unless}}
```

That should check for `undefined` as well as other falsy values.